# MetaMask showing incorrect price. Could be a RPC error

Tags: blockchain, metamask, rpc

MetaMask is showing fictitious $USD value displayed in MetaMask for $(sample)this was MetaMask support response:

This is out of scope for MetaMask Support; however, I can share with you our source code which you can review at https://github.com/metamask and our dev docs are found here: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/

For more assistance, I recommend reaching out to the broader community on stack exchange:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

After I explained that the $USD value was present and seems to be calculating 1 ETH - (samplecoin)

It looks like the native token prices are pulled through the network's RPC and the ones pulled from coingecko are using APIs.

Just wondering if anyone can help? Thank for your time. Block is currently in auditing phase and very little liquidity is being used for testing.